# Passing data to nlopt in Rcpp?

Tags: r, rcpp, armadillo, nlopt

This is a rather simple question, but I haven't been able to quite find the answer on the web yet.

Wishing my latest attempt, here is latest compiler output:
note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'double (unsigned int, const double *, void *, void *)' to 'nlopt_func' (aka 'double (*)(unsigned int, const double *, double *, void *)') for 2nd argument

From this error I surmise that I am now wrapping or 'type casting' the data argument correctly and also the parameter vector.  The discrepency between the third input, the gradient, confuses me.  As I am calling a gradient free optimization routine.

Here is a simple linear regression with a constant and a variable:

```
#include "RcppArmadillo.h"

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(nloptr)]]
//#include <vector>
#include <nloptrAPI.h>
using namespace arma;
using namespace Rcpp;

typedef struct {
  arma::mat data_in;
} *my_func_data;

typedef struct {
  double a, b;
} my_theta;

double myfunc(unsigned n, const double *theta, void *grad, void *data){

  my_func_data &temp = (my_func_data &) data;
  arma::mat data_in = temp->data_in;

  my_theta *theta_temp = (my_theta *) theta;
  double a = theta_temp->a, b = theta_temp->b;

  int Len = arma::size(data_in)[0];
  arma::vec Y1 = data_in(span(0, Len-1), 1);
  arma::vec Y2 = data_in(span(0, Len-1), 2);
  arma::vec res = data_in(span(0, Len-1), 0) - a*Y1 - b*Y2 ;
  return sum(res);
}


// [[Rcpp::export]]
void test_nlopt_c() {

  arma::mat data_in(10,3);
  data_in(span(0,9),0) = arma::regspace(40, 49);
  data_in(span(0,9),1) = arma::ones(10);
  data_in(span(0,9),2) = arma::regspace(10, 19);

  my_func_data &temp = (my_func_data &) data_in;

  double lb[2] = { 0, 0,}; /* lower bounds */
  nlopt_opt opt;
  opt = nlopt_create(NLOPT_LN_NELDERMEAD, 2); /* algorithm and dimensionality */
  nlopt_set_lower_bounds(opt, lb);

  nlopt_set_min_objective(opt, myfunc, &data_in );

  nlopt_set_xtol_rel(opt, 1e-4);
  double minf; /* the minimum objective value, upon return */
  double x[2] = {0.5, 0.5};  /* some initial guess */
  nlopt_result result = nlopt_optimize(opt, x, &minf);
  Rcpp::Rcout << "result:" << result;
    return;
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve] including the error message?

Comment: See the example [RcppArmadilloNLoptExample](https://github.com/jchiquet/RcppArmadilloNLoptExample) package construction and [issue ticket that inspired it](https://github.com/jyypma/nloptr/issues/39)

Comment: After inserting my best guess at your headers I tried to compile your example. I am getting different errors: "invalid conversion". This basically means that the calling signatures you are using are not correct.

Comment: I added my headers if it helps.

Comment: I have played around with these calling signatures, but haven't managed to find a solution.  I don't really have a background with programing, so my attempts have been mostly guesses.

Comment: Please see the NLopt docs, in particular https://nlopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/NLopt_Reference/#objective-function. Your `myfunc` is using the wrong arguments. You cannot use Armadillo types directly.

Comment: Ralf, may I ask where you saw the specific 'arma' type prohibition, I don't recall reading it and wasn't able to get a search result for 'arma' or Armadillo on the nlopt documentation website or the nloptr pdf.  I stumbled into the type cast solution above, in my updated example.

Comment: The "arma prohibition" is not part of the nlopt documentation but of the way C++ works. C++ is strongly typed, so you cannot simply insert some other type that "looks similar". If a `double *` is requested, you should pass in a `double *`. And if a function taking a `double *` as argument is needed, you should supply that. BTW, please see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) for info on replying in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it figured out, stupid answer turns out to be correct, just change 'void' to 'double', no clue why.  Anyway, the example code needs some improving but it works.

```
#include "RcppArmadillo.h"

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(nloptr)]]
//#include <vector>
#include <nloptrAPI.h>
using namespace arma;
using namespace Rcpp;

typedef struct {
  arma::mat data_in;
} *my_func_data;

typedef struct {
  double a, b;
} my_theta;

double myfunc(unsigned n, const double *theta, double *grad, void *data){

  my_func_data &temp = (my_func_data &) data;
  arma::mat data_in = temp->data_in;

  my_theta *theta_temp = (my_theta *) theta;
  double a = theta_temp->a, b = theta_temp->b;

  int Len = arma::size(data_in)[0];
  arma::vec Y1 = data_in(span(0, Len-1), 1);
  arma::vec Y2 = data_in(span(0, Len-1), 2);
  arma::vec res = data_in(span(0, Len-1), 0) - a*Y1 - b*Y2 ;
  return sum(res);
}


// [[Rcpp::export]]
void test_nlopt_c() {

  arma::mat data_in(10,3);
  data_in(span(0,9),0) = arma::regspace(40, 49);
  data_in(span(0,9),1) = arma::ones(10);
  data_in(span(0,9),2) = arma::regspace(10, 19);

  my_func_data &temp = (my_func_data &) data_in;

  double lb[2] = { 0, 0,}; /* lower bounds */
  nlopt_opt opt;
  opt = nlopt_create(NLOPT_LN_NELDERMEAD, 2); /* algorithm and dimensionality */
  nlopt_set_lower_bounds(opt, lb);

  nlopt_set_min_objective(opt, myfunc, &data_in );

  nlopt_set_xtol_rel(opt, 1e-4);
  double minf; /* the minimum objective value, upon return */
  double x[2] = {0.5, 0.5};  /* some initial guess */
  nlopt_result result = nlopt_optimize(opt, x, &minf);
  Rcpp::Rcout << "result:" << result;
    return;
}
```